# accessing "models" of a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this in my javascript console:

```
r {length: 1, models: Array[1], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
    _byId: Object
    length: 1
    models: Array[1]
        0: r
            _changing: false
            _events: Object
            _pending: false
            _previousAttributes: Object
            attributes: Object
                collection: Array[20]
                created_at: Wed Mar 27 2013 03:24:31 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
                __proto__: Object
            changed: Object
            cid: "c26"
            collection: r
            __proto__: s
            length: 1
        __proto__: Array[0]
    __proto__: s
```

I should have paid attention in class... but how can I access that "collection: Array[20]"? Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get array
r.models[0].attributes.collection
```

Should get you to the **collection** belonging to the first model in the models array.

If you want an individual element in the array:-

```
// Get first element of collection on first model
r.models[0].attributes.collection[0]
```

Comment: thanks. I was doing r.models[0].collection and it kept me going in circles!

Comment: My top tip for "Javascript discovery" ( we all have to do it ) is to play with the Chrome debugger.  Really teaches you a lot.

Comment: Yep, that's where I was doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like backbone.js collection so you can get to that array by doing this:

```
// Get model by index in collection
var collection = r.at(0).get('collection')

// Or get model by client id (cid)
var collection = r.getByCid('c26').get('collection')
```